# media queries for HTML5 background video

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, html5-video

I need help with my new website. I have a HTML5 background video on autoplay. The video is self hosted. The problem is, when the page shrinkes, it obviously looks nasty. Actually, the video does not play when viewed on a smartphone.
Here is the code for my video :

```
                <video id="background_video" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" poster="img/Deer_Picture.png">
                <source src="img/deer_eating_leaves.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="img/deer_eating_leaves.webm" type="video/webm">
                Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
```

And the CSS :

```
video { 
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 90%;
width: auto;
height: auto%;
z-index: -100;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);}
```

I would like to have a green background instead of the video when viewed on a smartphone. To understand what's going on, here is the website : repeltecusa.com
As well, I would like the h2 text to take all the space. I am currently using `vw` instead of `px` or `em` for the text so that it shrinkes on small devices.

Thanks

Comment: you can put background on your `hero-slides` id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, which just removes displaying the video and adds a green background to the slides:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
         #hero-slides {
             background: green;
        }

        #background_video{
            display:none;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try it out ;)